# how to restore access to MySQL after deleting all privileges?

Tags: mysql, password, accounts

Ok, I know I'm stupid. I deleted all privileges to MySQL, I have access to root account on host. Is there any way to add account to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all stop mysql & backup /var/lib/mysql or wherever the data files are on your system.

Then from a clean mysql install elsewhere tar up /var/lib/mysql/mysql and put it on the broken system.

Then re-add your users & permissions.

Of course if you have backed up the mysql database you can do this more quickly.